# Connect two computers to internet using a switch and ethernet cables

Tags: networking, connection, ip, ethernet

I have an internet ethernet port in the wall at my office at work. I have two pcs in my office. Since there is only one port, I got a switch and connected it to ethernet wall port. I connected the first pc1 to the switch using ethernet cable and it works fine, I then connected the second pc2 to the switch as well but it doesn't work, it says

> "Local Area Connection" doesn't have a valid IP configuration

I tried tested switching cables and ports in the switch but still the same problem. And if I connected pc2 directly to the wall port it works well and connected to the internet.

Both pcs has their IP and DNS obtained automatically. I'm not sure why this is happening? and how to fix it so that both computers can connect to the internet simultaneously?

Comment: have you tried using a static IP address? Have you looked at what IP address each of the PC's are using?

Comment: @JamesLingham But is there a way I can connect them using Automatic ips? As I don’t want to use static ones.

Comment: Windows should be configured to use dhcp so it would get an automatic IP. But I don't know how the network is configured at your office. It could be that the router only gives ip address to known pc's.

Comment: @RonNabuurs but both pcs connect to the internet if I connect them individually to the wall port, which means the router (which I have no access to or can even see) knows both pcs.

Comment: @Tak why do you not want to use static? Are they both being issues IP addreses? can you run IPCONFIG through CMD and let me know the IPv4 address?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check with the network administrator.

It's quite possible that your are neither allowed to install your own switch in the company network nor does the network support this mode of operation (e.g. using 802.1X port authentication).

With no port monitoring or authentication your simple switch would work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware than you can cause a layer 2 loop especially with "generic" switches that can participate in the layer 2 election.

I would recommend speaking with the network admin.

Now why this doesn't work, there are lots of possibilities like layer 2 security for example limiting the number of mac addresses on the physical port (for example 2: one for the PC and one for the VOIP phone).

Answer (score -3):

[Ethernet splitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Akh.jpg)

I suggest you use that instead of the switch.

Comment: I don't want to use a splitter as I want both pcs to be able to connect locally to each other.

Comment: Then you would need to configure the switch

Comment: Simple electric splitting requires a split/join adapter on each side, limiting the connection to 2x 100 Mbit/s.